# Turn NLog on and off

Tags: c#, nlog

I recently started using NLog to log data in a table in my database. It seems to work perfectly fine.

Now I wanted to add a toggle in my app so I can quickly enable or disable all the Logging. Is there a nice and easy way to do that with NLog?

The only way I have found so far is having autoReload set to true and then letting a button comment out or back the NLog.config file. That feels very shady and cumbersome though and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it!

Comment: I don't know if NLog has that facility but [Serilog](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/10/dynamically-changing-the-serilog-level/) does if you are interested in switching.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```cs
LogManager.DisableLogging();
LogManager.EnableLogging();
```

Another option:

```cs
LogManager.Factory.GlobalThreshold = LogLevel.Off;
```

Which makes it possible to globally only log fatal errors etc.

Last, but not least, 
this could be configured on rule level, see `LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules` then.